# What is the condition that an equality operator (==) cause a compile error in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

What is the condition that an equality operator (==) cause a compile error in Kotlin?

Comparing same types is ok, of course.

```
fun compare1(x: Int) = x == 1
```

Comparing different types cause an error:

```
fun compare2(x: String) = x == 1
```

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'String' and 'Int'

But comparing to generic type is ok though T may be String:

```
fun <T> compare3(x: T) = x == 1
```

Comment: The compiler is not able to tell you if this is going to fail or not, how should it be able to if T can be anything. But of course this can raise runtime errors.

Comment: @phaen If an `equals` can throw exceptions, it's a bad implementation :)

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I didnt state anything else, just said that the compiler cannot be aware of this (this is as you said just a bad implementation from TA), so you do not get an error on compiling.

Comment: You said it could raise runtime errors, but it won’t. It will just return false.

Answer (score 1):

`==` can't be applied to incompatible types, i.e. such that one object can't have both types simultaneously. Note that this applies even in cases where it would actually return `true`:

```
class X(val n: Int) {
    override fun equals(other: Any?) = x is Int
}

public fun main(){
    println(X(0) == 0) // Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'X' and 'Int'
}
```

on assumption that `equals` "shouldn't" return `true` for incompatible types.

So in `compare3` what matters is not that `T` may be `String`, but that it may be `Int`, so the comparison *sometimes* makes sense.